# How to release PCM on gstalsasrc.c when it paused?

Tags: alsa

When AudioRecorder app is paused, gstreamer alsa source still open PCM.

I tried to call unprepare, close when state is PLAYING_TO_PAUSED.

> gst_alsasrc_change_state()
>
> . . .
>
> case GST_STATE_CHANGE_PLAYING_TO_PAUSED:
>
> ```
>  gst_alsasrc_unprepare(alsa);
>  gst_alsasrc_close(alsa);
> ```
>
> . . .

but gstreamer still call snd_pcm_readi() like below

> /alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
>   /gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
>   /alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
>   /gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
>   /alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
>   /gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
>   /alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
>   /gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5

How to release PCM on gstalsasrc.c when it paused?

Here is the log

`/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:1102:gst_alsasrc_read: gst_alsasrc_read()
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:1102:gst_alsasrc_read: gst_alsasrc_read()
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:251:gst_alsasrc_change_state: GST_STATE_CHANGE_PLAYING_TO_PAUSED
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:258:gst_alsasrc_change_state: call unprepare
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:917:gst_alsasrc_unprepare: gst_alsasrc_unprepare()
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:933:gst_alsasrc_unprepare: gst_alsasrc_unprepare() done
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:261:gst_alsasrc_change_state: call close
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
systemd[1]: app-logic-voicerecorder.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
. . .
systemd[1]: Unit app-logic-voicerecorder.service entered failed state.
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:941:gst_alsasrc_close: gst_alsasrc_close()
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:957:gst_alsasrc_close: gst_alsasrc_close() call snd_pcm_close()
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:977:gst_alsasrc_close: gst_alsasrc_close() done
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:263:gst_alsasrc_change_state: set isPCMOpened = FALSE
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1318:snd_pcm_readi: alsalib error: PCM not set up
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:990: snd_pcm_delay: Assertion pcm' failed.
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:988:xrun_recovery:<alsasrc0> xrun recovery -5: Unknown error -5
/alsa-lib/1.0.29-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.29/src/pcm/pcm.c:1315: snd_pcm_readi: Assertionpcm' failed.
start-stop-daemon[831]: No /usr/bin/app-logic-voicerecorder found running; none killed.
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsaplugin.c:71:plugin_init: binding text domain gst-plugins-base-1.0 to locale dir /usr/share/locale
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsaplugin.c:71:plugin_init: binding text domain gst-plugins-base-1.0 to locale dir /usr/share/locale
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasink.c:357:gst_alsasink_init: gst_alsasink_init()
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:361:gst_alsasrc_init: gst_alsasrc_init
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:382:gst_alsasrc_getcaps: gst_alsasrc_getcaps
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:386:gst_alsasrc_getcaps: device not open, using template caps
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:382:gst_alsasrc_getcaps: gst_alsasrc_getcaps
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:386:gst_alsasrc_getcaps: device not open, using template caps
/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.2.4-r0/git/ext/alsa/gstalsasrc.c:191:gst_alsasrc_set_property: gst_alsasrc_set_property`

Comment: I'm not sure that you got this `PLAYING_TO_PAUSED` at all, add some debug log that `unprepare()/close()` is calling. If I understand correct after receiving `P_TO_P` function `snd_pcm_pause()` should be called. But there is some notice about this function inside pcm driver `this function works only on the hardware which supports pause feature.`. So first add debug log and check if it triggers at all.

Comment: I added the log to main comments. I added gst_alsasrc_unprepare(), gst_alsa_close() at PLAYING_TO_PAUSED. but  snd_pcm_readi() is called for a moments. then Assertion 'pmc' failed and process killed.